# Android: getting Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

```
public BinderData(Activity act, List<ScheduleItem> _items) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    items = _items;
}
```

When  i try it

```
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
BinderData bindingData = new BinderData(this.getActivity(), SomeArray);
```

inside  a `onCreateView` it works fine. But, Can bind a list in `OnCreate` method.

Comment: remove this and use just getActivity() and try.

Comment: @Raghunandan The method getActivity() is undefined for the type MainActivity MainActivity.java

Comment: if its activity class you can use the context as `MainActivity.this`.

Answer (score 0):

In Android we have a method called **getCallingActivity()** by using this we can know, Hope it helps you.